# highcharts multiple line live graph

Tags: php, charts, highcharts

How can I make multiple lines? This code works with only one line .

On the graph displayed only dspower value

How can I display dspower and uspower value?

```html
<script>
        var chart; // global
        function requestData() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'data.php', 
                success: function(point) {
                    var series = chart.series[0],
                        shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is longer than 20


                    chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);


                    setTimeout(requestData, 1000);  
                },
                cache: false
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'line',
                    events: {
                        load: requestData
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Live random data'
                },


                  legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
    },

                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickPixelInterval: 150,
                    maxZoom: 20 * 1000
                },
                yAxis: {
                    minPadding: 0.2,
                    maxPadding: 0.2,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Signalli',
                        margin: 80
                    }
                },
                         series: [{}]


            });     
        });

        </script>
```

And php code on `data.php`

```
<?php
   $dspower = "65";  //dspower value is always different
   $uspower = "109";  ////dspower value is always different
   $ds1= json_decode($dspower);
   $x = time() * 1000;
   $a = array($x,$ds1);
   $ret = $a;
   echo json_encode($ret);
 ?>
```

On data.php the output looks like: [1472210448000,53.9]

Comment: In your php you are not using $uspower, it will not be visible in output so your chart will not be able to use it. Maybe you can use an array with $dspower and $uspower?

Comment: I know that I have not used $uspower , I have tried in various ways but have not succeeded

Comment: You need two series if you want two lines. Your code is pushing one value to one series ( chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift); ) You need to 1) add a second series, and 2) add a point to both of them while looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You are only specifying one series in your chart code.

2) You are only updating one series in your update loop.

To account for both series in your chart config, change this:

```
series: [{}]
```

To :

```
series: [{ 
  name: 'DSPOWER Series'
},{
  name: 'USPOWER Series'
}]
```

This sets two named series, and you can then add data to each of them.

In your **data.php** file, return both values

```
$return_data = array(
  'dspower' => $dspower_value,
  'uspower' => $uspower_value
);
echo json_encode($return_data);
```

Then in your ajax success function, access both of the returned values, and update each series accordingly:

```
success: function(data) {
  var series1 = chart.series[0],
      series2 = chart.series[1],
      shift = series1.data.length > 20,
      parsedData = $.parseJSON(data);

  series1.addPoint(parsedData.dspower, false, shift);
  series2.addPoint(parsedData.uspower, false, shift);
  chart.redraw();

}
```

Code is approximate and may need adjustment.